# Automatic updates in tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, post-commit, svn-hooks

(I do not speak English well. Sponsored by someone who understands I will edit it!)

The Windows 7 version of source control, I use the following programs:
VisualSVN Server
tortoisesvn

I have a PHP project and the the team is doing on the network.
For each commit, the version that is runs on the server and the capabilities be automatically updated in the repository hooks directory file post-commit.bat wrote the following code. But after every commit and the Folder Lock can not be done!

But if I manually run the post-commit.bat file update is done

What is the problem?

```
@ echo off


echo == Initiating system instance variables ...
echo. - Setting the variables ...

:: Here you need to make some changes to suit your system.
set SOURCE = E: \ xampp \ htdocs \ mycode
set SVN = C: \ Program Files \ TortoiseSVN \ bin

:: Unless you want to modify the script, this is enough.

echo. % SOURCE%
echo. % SVN%
echo. + + Done setting variables.
echo.
echo == Updating source from SVN
echo. - Running update ...
"% SVN% \ TortoiseProc.exe" / command: update / path: "% SOURCE%" / closeonend: 2
echo. + + Done.
```

Comment: Your hook only update Site-WC, **where** you expect to see "version - date" information? In expanded keywords in source?

Comment: I did not understand your question @LazyBadger Badger. Please explain!

Comment: Make sure that VisualSVN Server service account ("Network Service" by default) has access to all paths. E.g. to **E:\xampp\htdocs\mycode** and to **C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin**

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseProc can't work without user intervention, you have to press at least one button by hand on update. Which is impossible for hooks - they doesn't have any GUI and two-side communication channels.

You **must** update your WC from hook, using *only* CLI-version of SVN-client